# QGIS 3.x issue with PG hstore colums

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, query, imposm

I have a PostgreSQL 9.6 database with tables created by imposm that include a hstore column. This hstore column looks fine in pgAdmin4.

[image: 1]

In QGIS 3.6 or 3.12, it shows up in the attributes table [image: 2], but differently : no more " =>" but a simple colon. The issue is that this field is not query-able by QGIS, as no information shows up while filtering [image: 3]

Field properties inform that the field is not a Qstring but a QvariantMap type. [image: 4]

Is there a way to fix this to get a fully usable hstore column in QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SQL syntax to query/filter the hstore column

```
"hstore" -> 'amenity' = 'clinic'
```

PS: naming a column using a data type name can only lead to issues...

For rule based styling (and other functions where the filtering is done in QGIS and not in the DB), you would use the QGIS syntax:

```
map_get("hstore",'amenity') = 'clinic'
```

Comment: Thanks for the SQL tip (that does work) and the naming advice: I renamed my hstore column tags_hstore, does it seem OK?

Comment: @Severin yes, with the new column name there is no risk of confusing the DB between a column or a function/type name!

Comment: The SQL tip does not work though in the Expression String builder (for query or rule-based symbology) that informs that: Expression is invalid. Can it be adapted to work there as well?

Comment: @Severin see edit with the QGIS syntax

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!